# AngularJS nested ng-repeats in a table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a load of data for users' availability by hour for several days in the form:

```
availData = { "date1":arrayOfUsers, "date2":arrayOfUsers, ... }

arrayOfUsers= [ userArray, userArray, ... ]

userArray= [ "username", "h0", "h1", "h2", ... "h23" ]
```

I have `arrayOfUsers` in that form so I can sort them according to their "h0".."h23" values.
This all works fine for one view, but I now want to use the same data and create a table containing the following for one selected "username":

```
date1  h0  h1  h2 ... h23
date2  h0  h1  h2 ... h23
...
```

So far I can do this which works:

```
<!-- rows of avail data... -->
<tr ng-repeat="(aDay,aUsers) in allAvailData track by $index">
 <td >{{aDay}}</td>
 <td ng-repeat="aUser in aUsers" ng-show="aUser[0]=='YR005'" >
   <span ng-repeat="hour in aUser track by $index" ng-show="!$first">{{hour}}
   </span>
 </td>
</tr>
```

giving a 2-column table row: `"date" "h0h1h2h3h4"`

But what I really want is separate  entries... which **does not work**:

```
<!-- rows of avail data... -->
<tr ng-repeat="(aDay,aUsers) in allAvailData track by $index">
 <td >{{aDay}}</td>
 <span ng-repeat="aUser in aUsers" ng-show="aUser[0]=='YR005'" >
    <td ng-repeat="hour in aUser track by $index" ng-show="!$first">{{hour}}</td>
 </span>
</tr>
```

I've not been using angular for very long and I would like to know if this sort of thing is possible rather than just restructuring the data into another array.

Questions are:

1. Why does the attempt at nesting ng-repeat in  not work?
2. can I nest ng-repeat in another way ?
3. am I approaching this all wrong ?

Comment: Did you consider combining `availData`, `arrayOfUsers` and `userArray` in one data structure?

Comment: They are all in one data structure - do you mean levelling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you do something like

```
<tr ng-repeat="(aDay,aUsers) in allAvailData track by $index">
  <td >{{aDay}}</td>
  <td ng-repeat="hour in getSelectedUser() track by $index" ng-show="!$first">{{hour}}</td>
</tr>
```

Implement `getSelectedUser` method that returns a single item from a `arrayofusers` based on your filter logic.

Comment: Ah, yes - that avoids my attempt at 3 levels of ng-repeat, thanks

Comment: You can also define this selectedUser as a property on you scope, and update it on specific events.

Comment: Only one small tweak: I think it would be better to have it as a scope model rather than a function. Not only are performance problems frequently found to be based on a function called in expressions in the $digest loop, it allows Angular to have a better idea about what it actually has to pay attention to: in the future, it might allow Angular to use Object.observe to make the loop much faster. If it's in a function, without some kind of annotation, it will be hard for Angular to ever divine that.